# I want to replace word in cucumber feature file and be reflected in step definition immediately

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

```
 Scenario Outline: check  offer exist
    Then    validate user "<user>" has offer with offerId "<offerId>"
    Examples:
      |  user     | offerId |
      |  ccccc    |ccccccccc|
```

like in this scenario  i want to change the wording of step without creating new one

change reflected immediately in the step definition file

Comment: Can you show the example of "changing the wording" ?

Comment: Are you looking for a refactoring tool that allows you to rename a step?

Comment: use a refactoring tool but it change word  both in  feature file and method in step definition file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation:

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/step-definitions/?lang=java

Step definitions can have regex.